# 'NewWindow' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, react-new-window

I'm trying to open a new window in my react app. I've come across this nice library: [`react-new-window`](https://github.com/rmariuzzo/react-new-window).

Even though I do exactly as the documentation says (I think) I get an error.

Here's my `App.tsx` from my SSCCE:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import NewWindow from "react-new-window";

function App() {
    const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false)
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <button onClick={() => setOpen(!isOpen)}>Open</button>
            { isOpen && <NewWindow>Hello!</NewWindow> }
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Here's my `package.json` if it matters:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0",
    "react-new-window": "0.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

And here's the error I get:

```
ERROR in src/App.tsx:10:26
TS2786: 'NewWindow' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'NewWindow' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/alundblad/tmp/new-window-repro/my-app/node_modules/@testing-library/react/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
     8 |         <div className="App">
     9 |             <button onClick={() => setOpen(!isOpen)}>Open</button>
  > 10 |             { isOpen && <NewWindow>Hello!</NewWindow> }
       |                          ^^^^^^^^^
    11 |         </div>
    12 |     );
    13 | }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is it a bug in the library?

I've found [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/utr4q?file=/src/viewer.js) example that *is* working, but I can't figure out what's different from my code.

If I change to react 18 I get a slightly different error:

```
ERROR in src/App.tsx:10:26
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: INewWindowProps | Readonly<INewWindowProps>): NewWindow', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<NewWindow> & Readonly<INewWindowProps>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: INewWindowProps, context: any): NewWindow', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<NewWindow> & Readonly<INewWindowProps>'.
     8 |         <div className="App">
     9 |             <button onClick={() => setOpen(!isOpen)}>Open</button>
  > 10 |             { isOpen && <NewWindow>Hello!</NewWindow> }
       |                          ^^^^^^^^^
    11 |         </div>
    12 |     );
    13 | }
```

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/rmariuzzo/react-new-window/issues/112) post which describes the same problem. No answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may happen by using incompatible dependencies in my experience.

I could sort it out by uninstalling and re-installing the doubtable packages one by one.

e.g. `@testing-library/react` 13.0 seems to require React 18 in its dependencies.

I could launch your app without testing libraries.

So please remove the following packages

```
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
```

And try to re-install. (I didn't test after installing them, but it should work)

These testing dependencies are correctly tested.

```
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.1.0",
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I got react 18 out of create raect app, then downgraded to 17 to reflect my actual setup. I got my SSCCE working thanks to your hint. Trying to mimic this setup in my real project now, but it's so much bigger so there's so much else going on. I'll report back if I have an update.

Comment: @aioobe Yeah, it must be tricky in the big project. A week ago, I spent much time to sort it out in the big project. Hope you figure it out soon.